# How to get/see plot of resultant series function/system in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, transfer-function

I am using MATLAB for series interconnection of two systems as shown in the code snippet below . How can I see/display the final resultant series transfer function in graph form (`sys` in my code)?

```
clc
clear all
close all
num1=[2];
den1=[3 4];
num2=[3];
den2=[4 1];
sys1=tf(num1,den1);
sys2=tf(num2,den2);
sys=series(sys1,sys2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that depends what kind of graph you want:

- Bode plot: `bode(sys)` (see https://uk.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/bode.html)
- Nyquist plot: `nyquist(sys)` (see https://uk.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/nyquist.html)
- Step response: `step(sys)` (see https://uk.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/step.html)
- Impulse response: `impulse(sys)` (see https://uk.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/impulse.html)

Here's the step response for example (done with Octave, not MATLAB, but it's the same code and same result):

[image]